# How to retrieve other parameter instead of id in gridview and detailview yii2?

Tags: php, list, yii2, multi-select, dropdown

In columns Role, Position, Department you see ids of these db tables "role","position","department".
[image: GridView]

How can I paste names instead of ids?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dou you need relational table data or different table data?

Comment: yeap, relational. Id in "role" table equals to role_id in "user" table

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **Detail view** check the relation in model and using the relation you do like this:-

```
'attributes' => [
    'title',             
    'relational_data',  
    [                    
        'label' => 'Field Name',
        'value' => $data->relation_table->field_name,
    ],        
],
```

For **Grid view**:-

```
[
    'attribute' => 'role_id',
    'value'     => function ($data) {
        return $data->relation_table->field_name;
    },
],
```

And your **Table relation** should be like this:-

```
public function getRelation_table()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Table::className(), ['relation_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Comment: I changed $data->relation_table->field_name to $data->role->name and it says: "Getting unknown property: backend\models\User::role".

Comment: First you check the relation available or not in your User model.

Answer (score 1):

Use anonymous function to change the value of attribute. Instead of simple

```
role_id,
```

on the list of GridView columns use array

```
[
    'attribute' => 'role_id',
    'value'     => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return $model->role_id;
    },
],
```

Now this will get you exactly the same result but you can customise it. For example:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'role_id',
    'value'     => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        switch ($model->role_id) {
            case 1:
                return 'User';
            case 2:
                return 'Moderator';
            case 3:
                return 'Admin';
        }
    },
],
```

Maybe you have got already created method with all the roles named in your User class:

```
public static function listRoles()
{
    return [
        1 => 'User',
        2 => 'Moderator',
        3 => 'Admin',
    ];
}
```

so you can use it in the GridView like:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'role_id',
    'value'     => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return User::listRoles()[$model->role_id];
    },
],
```

In case of relational data you can use it as well:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'role_id',
    'value'     => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return $model->role->name;
    },
],
```

`$model` is currently displayed instance of User.

Read more about GridView columns in the [Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#grid-columns).

Comment: Is it possible to implement this logic without hardcode with switch? I mean automatically paste the name of role instead of the id. I don't want to limit roles, because I have crud for these, also for positions and departments

Comment: I already gave you 3 options: hardcoded, static method, and relational table. You are not limited to these.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an addition to @Bizley solution, in case of relational data:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'role_id',

    'value'     => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return $model->role->name;
    },
],
```

Dont forget to make eager loading, you should add in **UsersSearch** into **search** function

```
 $query = Users::find()->with('role');// eager loading
```

instead of

```
 $query = Users::find();// lazy loading
```

and for filtering with role name add

```
 [
        'attribute' => 'role_id',
        'value'     => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
            return $model->role->name;
        },
       'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Role::find()
         ->asArray()- >all(), 'id', 'name')
    ],
```

This will add a combobox in the filtering filled with all roles names, if you want the input text filtering option there are another way to do that:

- remove the filter option added above:

  ```
  [
      'attribute' => 'role_id',
      'value'     => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
          return $model->role->name;
      },
   ],
  ```
- make joinWith instead of with

  ```
  $query = Users::find()->joinWith('role');
  ```

  - In **UsersSearch** **rules** change the role from integer to safe
  - In **search** function remove `'role' => $this->role,` and put instead
    `->andFilterWhere(['like', 'roles.name', $this->role])`